# The SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated unexpectedly

Tags: sql, ssas, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

I just created a new AWS Instance with Windows 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014 installed.

On configuration manager when I try to restart the service analysis Services I get this error.

> The SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated unexpectedly.

The computer is a domain controller, and I am using Ted Pattison's guide to install a SharePoint 2013 environment on this computer:

https://www.criticalpathtraining.com/the-best-sharepoint-2013-vm-build-guide-in-the-industry/

This is a lab env I am trying to setup,but I cant see more info on the event log, just this XML:

```
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7034</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-08-06T17:59:50.000930500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4995</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="636" ThreadID="4472" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>WingtipServer.wingtip.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">3</Data> 
  <Binary>4D005300530051004C005300650072007600650072004F004C004100500053006500720076006900630065000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: did you promote this server to be a DC after you installed SSAS?  What account is the service running as?

Comment: Yes correct, I am trying to setup a lab environment for sharepoint 2013, I used the amazon AWS image with w2012R2 and sql2014, and promoted it to DC.  Any idea how I can fix this? @steoleary

Comment: I can't believe someone wrote a guide suggesting you install SharePoint on a domain controller. That's in fact listed as an officially *unsupported* environment to install SharePoint in a production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have indicated in your reply to my comment that you have installed SQL server and then promoted the machine to a domain controller.

As this process wipes out any local accounts/groups etc (including all the ones created by the SQL installer), it doesn't migrate them to become domain accounts, the install is now broken and only an uninstall/reinstall will sort that out.

This is the same for lots of applications and is not unique to SQL server.  It is mentioned in this MSDN blog post too:

[Can I install SQL Server on a domain controller?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2011/07/01/can-i-install-sql-server-on-a-domain-controller.aspx)

Specifically this bit:

> After SQL Server is installed on a computer, you cannot change the computer from a domain member to a domain controller. **You must uninstall SQL Server before you change the host computer to a domain controller.**